# In a series with mixed data types, how to transform occasional lists and dicts into strings?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to clean up a json file with all my own Telegram messages from a certain chat where I receive notifications from a bot. Although the messages are pretty clean in the application, in the json file they get a bit messy. For example, the one-line Telegram message below...

```
Xparty P-Q D-21-01-30-20-12 (USDT_UNI): deal_284174394: Base order executed. 
Price: 21.03739122 USDT. Size: 127.06584296 USDT (6.04 UNI)
```

in the json file becomes:

```
['Xparty P-Q D-', {'type': 'phone', 'text': '21-01-30-20-12'}, ' (USDT_UNI): deal_284174394: 
Base order executed. Price: 21.03739122 USDT.  Size: 127.06584296 USDT (6.04 UNI)']
```

So I'm trying to clean up the messages in the json file to be able to work with them. Since all that noise follows certain patterns, I'm trying to add the patterns into a list and then replace them like so:

```
noise = [", {'type': 'phone', 'text': ", ", {'type': 'hashtag', 'text': ", "[", "]", "}, "]
df["messages"].str.replace('|'.join(noise), '', regex=False)
```

But my first problem is that in fact some of that noise happens because SOME of such messages are recorded as LISTS, others as DICTS, and only some are strings. So I believe I have to transform everything into strings first.

I was hoping a simply `df['messages'].apply(' '.join)` would do the trick, but since not all entries are LISTS, it's not working.

So my question is: how could I convert all Lists and Dicts from a certain series into strings given that there are different data types in the series? (hopefully, without having to fall back on loops!)

Comment: Does `df['messages']` contain the json data in its raw form `['Xparty P-Q D-', {'type': 'phone', 'text': '21-01-30-20-12'}, ' (USDT_UNI): deal_284174394: 
Base order executed. Price: 21.03739122 USDT.  Size: 127.06584296 USDT (6.04 UNI)'] ` ?

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes it's just a string e.g. ` GridBot (USDT_XRP): bot_32000: Bot is turned on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import json
df['messages'] = df['messages'].apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
```